# How to find the values of a matrix that make it consistent?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

So I have this system of equations:
\begin{eqnarray}
2x+ky+z&=&1,\\
x+z&=&0,\\
2x+y-z&=&k.
\end{eqnarray}

If I put this system in the form of an augmented matrix, I get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
2    &k&    1&    1\\ 
1   & 0&    1&    0  \\
2   & 1&    -1&    k
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
I then plug this augmented matrix in my calculator to get a row echelon form , which results in :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1   & k/2&    1/2&    1/2 \\
0&    1&    -1/k&    1/k \\
0&    0&    1&    -k²+1/3k-1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

***I want to find the values of $k$ which make the system consistent.***

Thus, I was thinking of taking into consideration the last row, which implies that $-k²+1/3k-1.$

So my question is : taking into consideration the denominator of $-k²+1/3k-1$, is the system inconsistent where $k=1/3$ (where the denominator is equal to $0$). Should I also seek inconsistency where the numerator is equal to zero?

Comment: You may want to use MathJax to edit your post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Also you may want to write down the equations in order to get an answer fast

Comment: Done that ... can you help me?

Comment: There are several questions in the handy list of related questions at right that cover this sort of problem. You ought to be able to find an suitable answer to your question among them.

Comment: I already checked and it they don't answer the question . I would like an explanation reguarding my answer, not other's answers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.. the denominator is also 3k-1 here, if i plug in 1/3 it makes the z undefined, due to the denominator being 0. So this implies that the system is consistent as long as K is not equal to 1/3. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I would really , really appreciate an answer. Its really important!

Answer (score 1):

This calculator (https://www.dcode.fr/matrix-row-echelon) gives the following augmented (reduced) matrix (so check whether your reduced matrix is correct):
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &0 &\frac{k^2-1}{3k-1}\\
0 &1 &0 &-\frac{k-3}{3k-1}\\
0 &0 &1 &-\frac{k^2-1}{3k-1}.
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Your system is consistent only if the rank of your coefficient matrix is equal to that of the augmented matrix.  As the rank of the coefficient matrix is equal to $3$ (which is easy to see), the rank of the augmented matrix must be equal to $3$ for consistency.  It is easy to see that as soon as the elements of the fourth column are determined, the rank of the augmented matrix is $3$ too.  Since all elements of the fourth column are fractions with denominator

$$3k-1,$$

they are determined for all value of $k$ such that the denominator is not equal to zero, i.e.:

$$3k - 1 \neq 0,$$

or

$$k \neq \frac{1}{3}.$$

Then, the answer is: the system of linear equations is consistent for $k \in (-\infty,\frac{1}{3})\cup (\frac{1}{3},\infty).$